# Why and how does python truncate numerical data?

Tags: python, serialization, floating-accuracy

Am dealing with two variables here, but confused because their values seem to be changing (they loose precision) when I want to send them as URL parameters as they are.

Look at this scenario as I reproduce it here from the python interpreter:

```
>>> lat = 0.33245794180134
>>> long = 32.57355093956
>>> lat
0.33245794180133997
>>> long
32.57355093956
>>> nl = str(lat)
>>> nl '0.332457941801'
>>> nlo = str(long)
>>> nlo '32.5735509396'
```

So what is happening? and how can I ensure that when I serialize `lat` and `long` to strings and send them as part of a url's query string I don't lose their exact precision?

To clarify the situation:

1. The data originally comes to my module as floats (in a collection) from another module that creates them from calculations.
2. Precision is a sensitive issue here because this data is being used to do tracking and monitoring of sorts and wrong values might cause false-positives or unnecessary alarms.
3. There is no way to send the data over to the target engine (which listens via a restiful api) without serializing the data to strings (so i can place them in a query string  as params)

So what I needed was the best way to transform floats into strings with minimal loss of precision / information.

Comment: Why aren't you using `format()`?

Comment: Mutual enlightenment might be assisted if you were to edit your question to tell us (1) exactly how you get your original float values (2) why you believe that e.g. `'0.33245794180134'` is the best or required output value (3) what your "specs" actually say (4) what "loss of precision giving penalties at times" means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general if you use `'%.14f' % lat`, you are **LOSING PRECISION**.

To get full precision from a float, use `repr()`.

Example:

```
>>> lat = 1/3.
>>> lat
0.3333333333333333
>>> str(lat).count('3')
12
>>> ('%.14f' % lat).count('3')
14
>>> repr(lat).count('3')
16
>>>
```

By the way, you are using an old Python.

```
>>> 0.33245794180134 == 0.33245794180133997
True
>>>
```

Pythons before 2.7 produce `repr(a_float)` by using 17 significant decimal digits because that will guarantee that `float(repr(a_float)) == a_float`. The new method is to use the smallest number of digits that will provide the same guarantee. Follow [this link](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.7.html) and Ctrl-F search for `repr()`.

If you are getting those numbers from an external source, then you could be losing precision by floating them and then serialising them with 14 decimal digits of precision.

If you are getting those numbers by calculation, then you could be losing precision by serialising them with 14 decimal digits of precision.

Summary: In general if you use '%.14f' % lat, **YOU** are losing precision -- not Python, not floating-point arithmetic, it's you..

Comment: this is indeed convincing, though my `python --version` shows `Python 2.6.5`. good that you've demonstrated a good argument for `repr` over my preferred approach. I'll consider this next time.

Comment: Yes, I've now really come to accept this as the better path. Because given that my data is in float form already, this preserves (and seems to improve?) the precision. I've changed over to this approach. Thanks John.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using string formatting to get desired precision.

```
>>> lat = 0.33245794180134
>>> lat
0.33245794180134
>>> "%.14f" % lat
'0.33245794180134'
>>>
```

**edit** to incorporate comments:

```
>>> '{0:.14f}'.format(lat)
'0.33245794180134'
>>>
```

Comment: Drop the "Decimal" business.  It's not helpful. Also, `'{0:.14f}'.format(lat)` works well.

Comment: @S.Lott: this is a very easy and indeed good approach. It's what I've adopted for this problem. I've tested both `'%.14f'` and `'{0:.14f}'.format(lat)` and they are wonderful and easy! thanks

Answer (score 2):

`str` is for human-readable representations. It rarely produces something that's equivalent or similar to an expression that produces the value fed to it. `repr`, on the other hand, is explicitly for that. In fact, it's what the REPL uses to give feedback about the results of expressions.

Note though that floats are still of finite precision and can't represent certain numbers exactly, regardless of how you serialize them to strings.

Comment: `>>> repr(0.33245794180134)` gives `'0.33245794180133997'`. Thus still i cant retain the number the exact way i had it at first! though `repr` is surely better than `str`

Comment: @mcnemesis: That falls under the "floats are inaccurate" law. Note though that even if you send a string exactly representing this number, the web service might very well convert it to a float and lose the precision you saved. Also note that the difference is 3e-17 = 0.00000000000000003, so it propably won't matter anyway.

Comment: thanks for the 'law', but i have to meet specs, and these values represent geo-locations with loss of precision giving penalties at times. anyway, the hints are good.

Comment: @mcnemesis: The equator is about 40,000,000,000 millimetres long. That's about 11 significant digits. You must have a very interesting application if you need more than 12 significant figures. Loss of "precision" is more likely to be caused by use of inappropriate formulas.

Comment: John gives a good demo of why `repr` is better. it's only when the requirement says `0.3334` should not equal `0.3333` that things become tight. but i now see your point.

Answer (score 0):

The Decimal type from the python standard library decimal module is definitely what you want. It allows you to keep up 28 digits of precision by default but doesn't force numbers into a binary floating point representation. The Decimal type also allows for mathematical operations involving numbers of other types without requiring conversion.

Your example converted to Decimal:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> lat = decimal.Decimal(repr(0.33245794180134))
>>> long = decimal.Decimal(repr(32.57355093956))
>>> lat
Decimal('0.33245794180134')
>>> long
Decimal('32.57355093956')
>>> repr(lat)
'0.33245794180134'
>>> repr(long)
'32.57355093956'
```

Adding a number to a Decimal:

```
>>> lat + 2
Decimal('2.33245794180134')
```

Avoiding the imprecision of binary floating point representations of numbers like 1.1:

```
>>> onepointone = decimal.Decimal(repr(1.1))
>>> onepointone
Decimal('1.1')
```

The decimal module in the python standard library is a real math module rather than the approximation of math you get with traditional floating point representations and floating point processors. I wish it was the default because in the dictionary the approximation floating point math we get by default in most languages should be the first example of the definition of useless.

Comment: -1 The OP needs to transmit a latitude and a longitude in bytes over the internet. He starts with floats. He hasn't said exactly how he got floats; possibilities: (1) float(a_string) (2) struct.unpack (3) calculations. `decimal` definitely can't help (1) and (2), and calculations of angles (or any kind of trig) don't seem to be available with `decimal` (apart from the "example" sin and cos functions in the docs). How can `decimal` be what the OP wants/needs??

Comment: indeed like @John Machin hints, `decimal` wont help in my situation because it requires that I first have a string representation of the numerical data - which sacrifices what am trying to pursue. You see, the data comes to my module as floats in a collection (from calculations in another module).

Comment: @John Machin @mcnemesis I'm not sure why you think you can't perform calculations of angles or trigonometric functions. Can you show me an example where you can't use a Decimal in place of a float?

Comment: Sure you can feed a decimal.Decimal instance to (say) math.cos ... but it's converted to float and the answer comes back as float -- all extra precision that might be available from decimal is LOST.