# Floating point precision variation in Python 2.7.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point-precision

If I run the following code in Python 2.7.5 console:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.radians(0.000001)
```

I get

```
1.7453292519943295e-08
```

However, if I put the same code in a file:

```
$ cat floatingtest.py
import math
print(math.radians(0.000001))
```

And run it, I get:

```
$ python.exe floatingtest.py
1.74532925199e-08
```

**Why the difference in floating point precision when running code in a script vs. running code in the console?**

(Python 3.3 doesn't seem to have this 'issue'. Both ways return the same high-precision value.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, skip the `print` in your .py file since that's the only difference you have (perhaps print concate the data somehow).

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5730873/1982962) about "losing precision"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the difference between `repr` and `str`:

```
>>> repr(math.radians(0.000001))
'1.7453292519943295e-08'
>>> str(math.radians(0.000001))
'1.74532925199e-08'
```

By default, `print` calls `str` on its arguments, but the REPL displays objects using `repr` when there is no assignment (and the return value is not `None`).

Answer (score 3):

It has no relation to precision only to the representation:

```
In [1]: import math    
In [2]: math.radians(0.000001)
Out[2]: 1.7453292519943295e-08    
In [3]: print math.radians(0.000001)
1.74532925199e-08    
In [4]: str(math.radians(0.000001))
Out[4]: '1.74532925199e-08'
```